# navigation bar does not show collapsed links when in small screen (phone screens)

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I use angular and need to include a JavaaScript code so that collapsed links in the navigation bar can be shown when on smaller screens instead it shows the icon with 3 bars and when I click on it it doesn't show the links. This code works on the HTML file. How do I include this JavaScript code in angular so that it can show the navigation bar on smaller/phone screens?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CSS Responsive Navigation Bar - Devbabu.Com</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#"><img src="logo.png" alt="DevBabu.com"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="close-nav"><button>×</button></div>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-bar">
                <button><i></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
    <script>
        const theBody = document.querySelector('body');
        const openNav = document.querySelector('.menu-bar button');
        const closeNav = document.querySelector('.close-nav button');
        const Navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');

        function showHide(){
            Navbar.classList.toggle('show');
            // bodyScroll();
        }

        openNav.onclick = showHide;
        closeNav.onclick = showHide;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to add this code to a js file in assets and access it from there but the navigation bar still doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example, so that we can help you. Only the JavaScript code doesn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about your question. As you said you're using angular, I don't know why you want to embed this as a `js`-file rather than using typescript.

I've created a minimal example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-11-playground-forked-nwf4v8?file=/src/app/app.component.css), where you can see how you would react to the click events, bind the function, and toggle the class.

If that was not the question, please refine your question and provide a minimal working example :)

### Edit

I've added another example, hope this answers your question.

```js
const theBody = document.querySelector('body');
const openNav = document.querySelector('.menu-bar');
const closeNav = document.querySelector('.close-nav');
const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');

openNav.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navbar.classList.add("open");
});

closeNav.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navbar.classList.remove("open");
});
```

```css
.navbar.open .close-nav, 
.navbar:not(.open) .menu-bar, 
.navbar.open nav {
  display: block;
}

.navbar:not(.open) .close-nav, 
.navbar.open .menu-bar, 
.navbar:not(.open) nav{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#"><img src="logo.png" alt="DevBabu.com"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar open">
      <button class="close-nav">×</button>
      <button class="menu-bar">Open</button>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
  Content goes here
</div>
```

Comment: I want to use nav bar which is responsive when in small screens. That javascript code makes the navbar respond to click events, thats why I need to add it to angular code. I'm new to angular, alternatively, please show me another way of doing it

Comment: No worries. I've already provided a minimal example that you can observe if you click on the codesandbox link. Please tell me whether this helps you. Otherwise, please elaborate on your question. :)

Comment: I have provided more code to make my question clearer. The code only shows css way of handling some events but I don't think it's applicable in this scenario. I just want the div to be visible when the button is clicked on phones.

Comment: I've added another example

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: Then please specify your question, or detail what doesn't work.